# How to handle old questions that today would be voted closed?

Tags: discussion

Today, I came across the question [Listing all the folders subfolders and files in a directory using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php). I'm curious as how to handle this question, as it is clearly a "gimme teh codez" question, yet it has over 20 votes, and several answers. Should this question be closed? In today's SO, this kind of question would be voted down quickly, possibly flagged for closure. But back in 2011(I wasn't aware of SO back then), this might have been acceptable(which is hard to believe). So how do I handle these types of questions? Flag them for closure? Down vote and move on?

Comment: Vote to close it if a close reason fits. Otherwise, downvote and move on. Unless the question has a very large number of views for the time it's been around _and_ a very large number of votes, mods won't lock it. (They can historical lock a question that they feel is extremely well-written and valuable, yet doesn't fit the rules. I believe they usually want a meta discussion first.) If it does not fit the rules of the site, it should be closed. If it's just a bad question, downvote it.

Comment: If the question is "useful" and doesn't violate any other rules, don't close it. You will see all over the site that there are "gimme teh codez" questions with zero effort that have hundreds or even thousands of upvotes. They get those upvotes by being useful to people running into the same problem. Sure there's plenty of "fairness" butthurt around these sorts of questions, but the fact is that they are part of the "repository of useful information" that SO strives to be.

Comment: @Mysticial That's a reason to not *delete* it.  It's not a reason to not *close* it.

Comment: @Servy Then let's see if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery) will get closed.

Comment: @Mysticial Why should it be closed?  What close criteria does it meet?  It seems poorly researched, which would be a reason to downvote it, but not a reason to close it.

Comment: "Gimme teh codez" and "no research effort". (I'm not advocating that it be closed. I'm just using it as an example.)

Comment: @Mysticial Neither of those are reasons to close *any* questions, regardless of it's votes/views/age.  They're reasons to downvote a question.  If the question actually meet some criteria for closure (I see none) then it should indeed be closed regardless of its views/votes/age.

Comment: @Servy I think we're talking past each other. Initially, I couldn't tell if you were saying that "gimme teh codez" and "no effort" questions were reasons for closure. (It used to be, until they removed those close reasons probably to specifically allow these sort of questions to live.)

Comment: @Mysticial Neither of those problems are, or have ever been, reasons to close a question.  They've both always been reasons to downvote a question.  I'm not sure why you thought that I said they were reasons for closure when I specifically said, "It seems poorly researched [...] but *not* a reason to close it."

Comment: @Servy "Not a real question" and "minimal understanding" were the reasons that used to be used. They had varying interpretations for different people, one of which included "gimme teh codez" and lack of research effort.

Comment: @Mysticial They *didn't* mean *either* of those things.  People incorrectly thought that they meant though things, even though they didn't, and abused them to close questions for those reasons even though they didn't mean the criteria that those reasons *actually* described.  As a result, they were re-worked into new reasons that helped to make their actual meanings clearer to help prevent misunderstandings from those voting to close.

Answer (score 8):

If the question meets any close criteria, feel free to vote to close it.  When the question was asked is irrelevant.

Comment: And as always, `closure != deletion`.  It just prevents any new (probably low quality) answers.